# libvncserver - example.c compilation error

Tags: c, vnc, vnc-server

Upon running the command `gcc example.c -lvncserver -o example`, where `example.c` is the file presented [here](https://libvnc.github.io/doc/html/example_8c-example.html), the error `example.c:141:19: fatal error: radon.h: No such file or directory` comes up.

I can not find any documentation on `radon.h` from `libvncserver` and cannot find this problem online. Am I making a simple (read: dumb) mistake?

Answer (score 1):

`radon.h` is not present on libvncserver documentation's examples directory or files directory, but is present in their github repository for download. Simply downloading and storing this file in the same directory as `example.c` is sufficient for it to compile.

https://github.com/LibVNC/libvncserver/blob/master/examples/radon.h